# Error encountered while pushing to the remote git repository on TFS2015

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015

When i try to push any git commits to TFS:2015 server, i faced the below error:

> Error encountered while pushing to the remote repository: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).

I want to mention that i open VS2015 as admin and i used Windows 10 operating system.
I also go to Credentials Manager and removed all the Windows and Web Credentials.

I think the issue happened with 2013 also.

I used VS2015 Community and VS 2013 professional.

Edit:

When i try to use command line, every thing will stop at this point from about 30 minutes:

```
git push -f origin develop
Counting objects: 258, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (235/235), done.
Writing objects: 100% (258/258), 11.50 MiB | 13.51 MiB/s, done.
Total 258 (delta 146), reused 1 (delta 0)
```

Comment: Ask the server admin to check the eventlog on the server, this looks like something that needs to be checked server-side, as the server is returning an error. It doesn't look like an authentication issue, as the error code would be different.

Comment: @jessehouwing  this issue not happened with the other team members, but you are right checking the event-log will clearly shown the error

Comment: It may have to do with the changes you're trying to push. Have you tried pushing them from the commandline to exclude the VS git implementation?

Comment: @jessehouwing I try to push from command line, please check the updates on the question

Comment: To help more with what is happening, could you type the following commands into Git Bash and then run your push again?

Comment: export GIT_TRACE=1

Comment: export GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1

Comment: @Marzouk The issue not happened with other members. Do you have the issue on other machine? Try access TFS on web access (Internet browser) > Code > Explorer > Select a file > Edit > Modify it > Click Save and check the result.

Comment: Try to clear client cache C:\Users\[user name]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\6.0

Comment: @Marzouk What's the result now? Do you solve this issue?

Comment: no, i try every single solution and the issue still exists